# Elapsed time in SSMS is consistently higher than SQL Server Execution Time - connection issue?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, connections

I have a fresh install of SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition on a pretty snappy laptop. I'm using it as a backend for an ASP.NET webapp. I noticed query timings that were consistently higher than I'd expect coming from a MySQL background.

For example, MiniProfiler shows `select * from Comments` is taking 30-50ms, when Comments has only one row in it. Simple things like that.

In investigating, I opened SQL Server Management Studio and issued a simple query:

```
set statistics io on
set statistics time on
go
select 1 as one;
go
set statistics io off
set statistics time off
go
```

This outputs what I'd expect:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

But in the right sidebar of SSMS, 'Aggregate Status > Elapsed Time' shows **77ms**. Running it multiple times shows timings varying between 50ms and 80ms.

I removed the timing commands and just ran `select 1 as one;` (again from SSMS). Profiler again shows 0ms execution times, but SSMS shows 55ms. My first question: **Is it unreasonable to expect (exponentially) better performance?** If SQL Server is just slow, I don't want to waste time on this. Have a hard time believing that, though.

At this point, I believe this is a connection issue, but I'm not sure where to start. I did disable McAfee's on-access protection, to no avail. I've also tried using SQL Server auth instead of Windows auth, also with no effect.

What are your thoughts? These 50ms hits for every query really add up on pageloads, and I believe we're also seeing this in production (I'm light on the details there).

Comment: Mybe [this](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/#identify_problem_query) will help

Comment: Getting results from client to server isn't instantaneous. Rendering the results in SSMS takes time, too. Even for very small data sets travelling a very short distance, it's reasonable that it would take a few milliseconds. I don't think it's fair to talk "orders of magnitude" difference when dealing with a trivial example where the total time is <100ms.  What happens when query time is 1 minute on the server. Does the client capture 1 minute, plus 77 milliseconds, or 77 minutes?

Comment: @AMtwo From what I've seen, it'd take 1m + 77ms. On Rails + MySQL, MiniProfiler shows queries returning in <1ms and pages rendering in 50ms. Here, I've yet to see a query under 20ms nor pageloads under 200ms. And that's a compiled language v. an interpreted one. Those 50ms queries add up fast.

Comment: Much like @sp_blitzerik has said... what happens if you use sqlcmd to run the query... what then? My guess - it'll be pretty fast... SSMS is known to be a very slow RBAR application.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Execution time server-side is 0ms, in both SSMS and in sqlcmd. My issue is that queries (even `select 1`) take 25ms+ according to MiniProfiler in ASP.NET, numbers that are backed up by the pageload time itself. I only include SSMS information to show that there appears to be an abnormally large transfer time between SQL Server and the consumer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're after a system that takes 0 ms to return and render results, good luck.

This doesn't mean that SQL Server is 'just slow', though I'm not sure what your expectations for grid rendering are.

The only way to see what your server is waiting on is to look at its wait stats. If you'd like a free script that does that, head [over here](http://firstresponderkit.org) and check out `sp_BlitzFirst` (full disclosure, I contribute to this open source project).

You can run it this way to look at your server's wait stats since it started up:

`EXEC sp_BlitzFirst @SinceStartup = 1`

Or this way to get a sampling during a window length of your choosing:

`EXEC sp_BlitzFirst @Seconds = 30, @ExpertMode = 1`

And if you find a system that returns and renders results in 0 ms, drop me a line! I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: I can't say I've ever worked with SQL Server beyond basic messing in the Data Explorer - but a basic MySQL select query will return results in 2 orders of magnitude less than this.

Comment: @ArtOfCode _Return_ or _Render_?

Comment: Return, to be fair. I haven't timed render, though I suspect it'd still be quicker.

Comment: @ArtOfCode You may suspect right. SSMS is **notoriously** slow to render grid results. That's why most people who seriously tune queries will avoid that step by discarding results (or whatever other mechanism -- assigning variables or dumping to temp tables).

Comment: I'm seeing the same timings in MiniProfiler on page loads, though, so I'm hesitant to chalk this up to grid rendering.

Comment: @Undo Post back when you've looked at wait stats. I'm giving you the best method to troubleshoot, here.

Comment: I just spun up an Azure website - using a separate SQL Server instance (so the bytes are going across the network). 2.6ms for a `SELECT *` according to MiniProfiler, the same measure I'm using locally - so an order of magnitude improvement. I'm working on getting stats using your script.

Comment: Okay, I've run the script. What am I interested in, specifically? I don't see anything that particularly sticks out, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Undo look for the section with 'wait stats' in it. That tells you what your server is primarily waiting on. If you have any questions about what's there, let me know. I'll be around for another 20 minutes this evening.

Comment: Yep, all I'm seeing for wait stats (when running my `select 1 as one` query a couple dozen times) are single-digit sub-millisecond waits on `WRITELOG`, `PAGEIOLATCH_UP`, and `PREEMPTIVE_OS_WRITEFILE`. There's also `TRACEWRITE`, 30 waits at 948ms per, but I suspect that's from Blitz itself?